# PHP, Google geocoding, passing information

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-geocoder

I have a php page.
The php page has a form, and when I click on the button, it calls the page itself. If the value is 'submit', then I call an API to display properties statistics.

This is working fine. But instead of using the location (passed with the form), I want to use the north east and south west coordinates returned by google geocode.

I've managed to geocode my location. But I'm struggling to pass the data from the geocode (javascript) to my php page.

What's the best practice?

Editing the description.

Here is my form call:

```
        <form action="http://www.propertycrunch.co.uk/investment-analysis/" method="post" onsubmit="nesw(this.location.value);">
            <input id="location" name="Location" class="searchbox"/> 
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" id="submitbutton" /> 
        </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function nesw(strAddress) {
        //initialize();
        var geocoder;
        var map;
        var address = strAddress;
        // set up Google map, pass in the heatmap function
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 6,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scaleControl: true
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("heatmap"), myOptions);
        if (address) {
            alert('Address: ' + address);
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location) ;
                    var ne = results[0].geometry.viewport.getNorthEast();
                    var sw = results[0].geometry.viewport.getSouthWest();
                }
            });

        }
        alert('coordinates: ' + ne + ' / ' + sw);
  } 
</script>
```

Regards,
Olivier

Comment: Can you provide the relevant code you're struggling with?

Answer (score 1):

Create 4 hidden fields for the 4 values(NElat,NElng,SWlat,SWlng) inside the form and set the values when you get the geocoding-result.

Comment: Hi Dr Molle. I thought the same. What I've now is a form that called the PHP page itself. There is a parameter and if the value is submit, then I process with calls to an API. I also display a google map. All work fine. Now, in my form call, I've add a onsubmit option that call a Javascript function. I want that function to geocode the location I've entered. I'm able to pass the address to my javascript function. But the geocoding is failing (or not returning anything). I'm not sure why. I will try to add the code in my main description as I don't think I can do it on the comment box.

Comment: You cannot do it that way, geocoding-results will be fetched asynchronous, so the form will be submitted before you receive the results.  You can cancel the submission of the form inside the function and submit the form as soon as you got the response. Of course you can also skip the clientside request and request the results by using PHP.